# Select last record added/updated in dgv

Tags: vb.net

How to select the last record which is added or updated in datagridview
This is how i add

```
 Insert into table (Name, AddDate) values ('" & Name & "', '" & Date.Now & "')"
```

After adding the record i refresh dgv

```
("Select * from table")
    Form1.DGV.DataSource = SQLDataset1.Tables(0)
```

And this is how i update record

```
("Update table Set Name='" & txtT.Text & "' , DateEdit='" & Date.Now & "' Where Town= '" & txtT.Text & "'")
```

Edit :

```
Public Sub addIt(Name As String)
        Try
            Dim addStr As String = "Insert into tableName (Name, AddDate) values ('" & Name & "', '" & Date.Now & "')"
            sqlcon.Open()
            SqlCom = New SqlCommand(addStr, sqlcon)
            SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlcon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

'Buton click event

```
  If Len(town) >= 3 Then
                        sql.addIt(town)
                        Msgbox("Added")
                        sql.resetDGV()
   End If

Public Sub resetDGV()
                sqlquery("Select * from tableName")
                Form1.dgv.DataSource = SQLDataset.Tables(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please post the whole code in one block?

Comment: @manuchao I will try my best but this code is splited all around the forms.

Comment: Now we just need your question, problem... :P

Comment: @manuchao after i add the record in database it should refresh the datagridview and select that row.  Same with edit

Comment: Which row the last one? Or the row you inserted? Why not using a DataTabe. If you update you could then Insert into sql-database and afterwards just add a new row to the Datatable.

Comment: @manuchao the row i inserted is the last row added which needs to be highlighted / selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are easier ways outside in the www. But this is the shortest so....

```
Public Sub addIt(Name As String) as int
        Dim insertedID as int = -1
        Try
            Dim addStr As String = "Insert into tableName (Name, AddDate) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID values ('" & Name & "', '" & Date.Now & "')"
            sqlcon.Open()
            SqlCom = New SqlCommand(addStr, sqlcon)
            returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(SqlCom.ExecuteScalar())
            sqlcon.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        return insertedID 
End Sub

  If Len(town) >= 3 Then
     Dim insertedID as int = sql.addIt(town)
     If insertedID = -1 Then return

     Msgbox("Added")
     sql.resetDGV()
     'Select
     SelectLastInsertedRow(insertedID)
  End If

Public Sub resetDGV()
    sqlquery("Select * from tableName")
    Form1.dgv.DataSource = SQLDataset.Tables(0)
End Sub

Private Sub SelectLastInsertedRow(id as int)
    For Each row as DataGridViewRow in dgv.Rows
        'Check if row belongs to the ID
        if(row == id) Then
          'Select
          row.Select = true
        End if 
    End For
End Sub
```

This code is not tested. But it should work :P

Comment: It has a lot fixes this code but at the end not working. You need to send id to sub when calling it. Also can't compare row and id type of string. For loop not working like this :( :(